# How can routers forward broadcast traffic?

Tags: router, ipv4

I was asked by an interviewer about the following question:

> Is there any way to make routers to forward Broadcast traffic?

I said no for the above question as routers break the broadcast domain.

He said "it is possible?" I have gone through lot of books, but it was no use.

Comment: The first hit when [googling "router forward broadcasts"](https://www.google.com/search?q=router+forward+broadcasts) is *[this cisco support forums thread](https://supportforums.cisco.com/thread/2106547)* about forwarding UDP broadcasts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the system. Cisco's will forward certain broadcast traffic (hint: google "ip helper-address")  Other protocols have specific mechanisms to forward ("relay") their broadcast traffic -- for example DHCP, normally it would cease being broadcast when relayed, but many system can be configured to broadcast the relayed request. (I personally do that so the pxe server can see the requests as well, and answer boot requests.)

Comment: As far as you know, is it possible somehow to use OpenVPN Tun, or Linux Kernel itself? If you know how to get it, could you update the answer please to show how it may be configured?

Answer (score 4):

You didn't specify a router vendor or network protocol, but let's assume it's a Cisco and IP (for the moment).

#### Example of forwarding IP broadcasts from 10.0.1.0/24 to 192.0.2.0/24

Assume IPv4 broadcast traffic enters the router like this:

```
  10.0.1.255            Gi0/0 +---------+              +---------+ Gi0/4
      --->      10.0.1.254/24 | Router1 |---{ WAN }----| Router2 | 192.0.2.254/24
 UDP port 55666               +---------+              +---------+
```

This configuration would forward the UDP broadcast traffic on port 55666 from *Router1:Gi0/0* to *Router2:Gi0/4*.  The `ip helper-address 192.0.2.255` command forwards the broadcast to 10.0.1.255 as 192.0.2.255 to *Router2:Gi0/4*.  The broadcast would then exit *Router2:Gi0/4* as an ethernet broadcast to IP address 192.0.2.255 (the IP subnet broadcast address).

*Router1's config*:

```
!
hostname Router1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 10.0.1.254 255.255.255.0
 !! if an IP broadcast matches the forward-protocol, send to 192.0.2.255
 ip helper-address 192.0.2.255
!
!! allow helper-addresses to forward UDP/55666 broacasts
ip forward-protocol udp 55666
```

*Router2's config*:

```
!
hostname Router2
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/4
 ip address 192.0.2.254 255.255.255.0
 !! Allow directed broadcasts to exit as an ethernet mac-layer broadcast.
 !!  This is the default setting, but is often turned off for security purposes
 ip directed-broadcast
!
```

#### Forwarding non-IP broadcasts across routers...

There are a few options... for instance:

- Use a router in [bridge mode](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk331/tk660/technologies_tech_note09186a0080094471.shtml)
- Use something like [DLSw](http://docwiki.cisco.com/wiki/Internetwork_Design_Guide_--_Designing_DLSw%2B_Internetworks#Figure%3a_Simple_Ethernet_DLSw.2B_configuration)

Comment: As far as you know, is it possible somehow to use OpenVPN Tun, or Linux Kernel itself? If you know how to get it, could you update the answer please to show how it may be configured?